# The arrow pointer in a TStringGrid

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Is it possible to add that arrow pointer thing to a String Grind in Delphi 7? You know what I mean, that arrow pointer that you can see at the left in a DBGrid.

Comment: Please don't put information in the title (like '(Delphi 7)') that you can include in the tags. The tag system works extremely well here, and repeating the information in the subject isn't necessary. Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, but not automatically. You would need to display a triangle manually. You can override **OnDrawCell** for your grid. It seems you need to set the **FixedCols** to 0 since it doesn't appear to redraw the fixed cells again when the row selection changes.

```
procedure TForm1.StringGrid1DrawCell(Sender: TObject; ACol, ARow: Integer;
  Rect: TRect; State: TGridDrawState);
var
  aCanvas: TCanvas;
  oldColor: TColor;
  triangle: array [0..2] of TPoint;
const
  spacing = 4;
begin
  if (ACol = 0) and (aRow = StringGrid1.Row) then
  begin
    aCanvas := (Sender as TStringGrid).Canvas;  // To avoid with statement
    oldColor := aCanvas.Brush.Color;
    // Shape the triangle
    triangle[0] := TPoint.Create(Rect.Left + spacing, Rect.Top + spacing);
    triangle[1] := TPoint.Create(Rect.Left + spacing, Rect.Top + Rect.Height - spacing);
    triangle[2] := TPoint.Create(Rect.Left + Rect.Width - spacing, Rect.Top + Rect.Height div 2);

    // Draw the triangle
    aCanvas.Pen.Color := clBlack;
    aCanvas.Brush.Color := clBlack;
    aCanvas.Polygon(triangle);
    aCanvas.FloodFill(Rect.Left + Rect.Width div 2, Rect.Top + Rect.Height div 2, clBlack, fsSurface);
    aCanvas.Brush.Color := oldColor;
  end;
end;
```

This draws a triangle in the box. You should get the general idea.

Comment: +1 this helped me a lot. btw in BDS2006 C++ I do not need to mess with fixed columns (so most likely in Delphi is the same). They are rendered this way as the rest of the cells. The only thing that needs to be done is program the clicking on them by using OnMouseDown event of the `TStringGrid`. Just got id working for my project (MYSQL table <-> TStringGrid with custom sortings and nested tables rules)

Answer (score 1):

Not automatically; it's not part of the standard `TStringGrid`. The "arrow pointer thing" is called the `row indicator`, and it's a feature added in `TDBGrid`. It's declared in `TDBGridOptions`, specifically `dgIndicator`, as seen below:

```
TDBGridOption = (dgEditing, dgAlwaysShowEditor, dgTitles, dgIndicator,
    dgColumnResize, dgColLines, dgRowLines, dgTabs, dgRowSelect,
    dgAlwaysShowSelection, dgConfirmDelete, dgCancelOnExit, dgMultiSelect);
```

Note that this is different from `TGridOption` declared in the `Grids` unit, which does not contain anything similar. (There is no `goIndicator` or equivalent.)

In order to get the indicator, you'd have to draw it yourself in the `OnDrawCell` event when you receive a `ACol` value of `0` with `ARow` equivalent to the `Grid.Row` value. There's an example of `TStringGrid.OnDrawCell` in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8602877/62576), although it's demonstrating setting a custom row height and not drawing the row indicator.